# Colimits of residually finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Every finitely generated  group is a colimit of a sequence of finitely presented groups. If every group in the sequence is residually finite what can one say about the colimit?

More precisely:
Is the colimit of a sequence of residually finite groups again residually finite?

Comment: Do you want to assume that the limit is finitely presented?

Comment: The filtering colimits (= inductive limits) of residually finite groups form the class of LEF groups. No, this is not necessarily residually finite, even if finitely generated. But finitely presented + LEF implies residually finite.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(a) There exists a finitely generated (f.g.) group that is an inductive limit of a sequence of epimorphisms of f.g. residually finite groups, and is not residually finite. The first such example is due to B.H. Neumann (1937) and I describe it below.

Write $Y=\{(i,j)\in\mathbf{Z}\times\mathbf{N}: |i|\le j\}$. View it as the disjoint union of the finite subsets $Y_j=\{(i,j): |i|\le j\}$; write $Y_{\ge m}=\bigcup_{j\le m}Y_j$. Let $W_m$ be the group of permutations of $Y_{\ge m}$ preserving each $Y_j$: it is residually finite (since it embeds in the (infinite) product of symmetric groups on the $Y_j$ for $j\ge m$ (note that $W_m$ is quotient of $W_{m-1}$ by a finite normal subgroup).

Let $t$ act on each $Y_j$, $j\ge 1$ as the transposition $0\leftrightarrow 1$. Let $c$ act on each $Y_j$ as the cycle $(-j,\dots,j)$. On $Y_j$, the images of $c$ and $t$ generate the symmetric group (on $2j+1$ letters). Then $c$ and $t$ define elements $c_m$, $t_m$ of $W_m$, acting on $Y_{\ge m}$. Define $G_m=\langle c_m,t_m\rangle\subset W_m$. Then clearly the image of $G_{m-1}$ in $W_m$ by the canonical projection ("forgetting $Y_{m-1}$") is $G_m$.

So we have epimorphisms $G_2\to G_3\to\dots$, and all are residually finite. Let $G$ be the inductive limit. The kernel of $G_2\to G_m$ is the set of elements of $G_2$ that are identity outside $\bigcup_{2\le j\le m}Y_j$. Hence the kernel of $G_2\to G$ the union of these kernels, namely the set of elements of $G_2$ with finite support (typical nontrivial such elements are $[t,c^ntc^{-n}]$ for $n\ge 2$). It is not hard to see that we can identify the quotient $G$ as the group acting on $\mathbf{Z}$ generated by the transposition $0\leftrightarrow 1$ and the shift $n\mapsto n+1$. This 2-generated group contains the group of finitely supported permutations of $\mathbf{Z}$, which is not residually finite, since it has an infinite simple subgroup of index 2 (Onofri 1929).

This example was rediscovered when the concept of LEF group was clarified (Stëpin  in the early 1980s, Vershik-Gordon in the 1990s).

---

(b) Edit 2: Here's an additional example with an inductive limit of finitely presented groups. [Edit 3: the example in (a) might work similarly, see (c) below]

For $n\le\infty$, let $M_n$ be the infinitely generated "right-angled Artin group" $$\langle x_m,y_m:m\in\mathbf{Z}\mid [x_p,x_q],[x_p,y_q]\text{ if } 0<|p-q|<n\rangle.$$
Note that $M_\infty$ is the restricted direct product $\bigoplus_{p\in\mathbf{Z}}F(x_p,y_p)$ of the free groups on 2 generators .

Using the obvious shift automorphism $x_p\mapsto x_{p+1}$, $y_p\mapsto y_{p+1}$, define, for $n\le\infty$ the $H_n$ as the semidirect product $M_n\rtimes\mathbf{Z}$.

Then $H_n$ has the presentation
$$\langle t,x_0,y_0\mid [x_0,t^px_0t^{-p}],[x_0,t^py_0t^{-p}]:1<|p|\le n\rangle. $$

This is a finite presentation for $n<\infty$. It is not hard to check in addition that this is a residually finite group.

But $H_\infty$ is a standard wreath product $F(x_0,y_0)\wr\mathbf{Z}$, which is not residually finite by an old remark of Gruenberg (1957).

---

Let's go back to (a), it might works too (i.e. with f.p. residually finite approximating groups). This is mostly similar to (b).

For $n\le\infty$, define the Coxeter group
$$Q_n=\langle x_p:p\in\mathbf{Z}\mid x_p^2,(x_px_{p+1})^3\;\forall p,[x_p,x_q],\;\forall p,q\text{ s.t. }2\le |p-q|\le n\rangle.$$

Note that $Q_\infty$ can be represented as the group of finitely supported permutations of $\mathbf{Z}$, $x_i$ acting as transposition $i\leftrightarrow i+1$. Consider the automorphism $x_i\mapsto x_{i+1}$ of $Q_n$ and define $L_n=Q_n\rtimes\mathbf{Z}$. Thus $L_\infty$ is the B.H. Neumann group of (a), which can be also represented as the group of those permutations of $\mathbf{Z}$ that act as a translation outside a finite subset, generated by transposition $0\leftrightarrow 1$ and by the shift $p\mapsto p+1$.

The group $L_n$ is presented, namely as
$$L_n=\langle t,x_0\mid x_0^2,(x_0tx_0t^{-1})^3,[x_0,t^px_0t^{-p}]:2\le p\le n\rangle,$$
which for $n<\infty$ is a finite presentation. I believe it can be checked that $L_n$ is residually finite if $n<\infty$. [The easy virtual retraction argument I have in mind in (b), however, doesn't work: Coxeter groups with odd exponents are a little more complicated that those with only even/infinity exponents.]

Comment: Am I reading correctly that every $Y_m$ should be $Y_{\geq m}$, and that adding the words "residually finite" to the first sentence makes it clearer?

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle thanks, indeed. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Is every $G_m$ finitely presented? What do you mean by the norm of $i$ when $i$ is a natural number?

Comment: Sorry, $i\in\mathbf{Z}$: fixed. No, indeed no $G_m$ is finitely presented. I'll expand the answer to provide an example where the sequence is made of finitely presented groups.

Comment: In example (a), you defined $c$ as a transposition and $t$ as a cycle.  But in the next paragraph you seem to (quite reasonably) mean the reverse.

Comment: @AndreasBlass indeed. I fixed it: the typo was in the second paragraph, and since indeed $c$ was confusing, I changed it to $x$, more consistently with (b) and (c).

Comment: @YCor Are you sure you fixed it? -- The last edit appears to have been *before* Andreas Blass' comment.

Answer (score 8):

The additive group $\mathbb Q$ is the colimit of sequence of copies of $\mathbb Z$.  Here $\mathbb Z$ is residually finite but $\mathbb Q$ isn't.

Comment: Is there any counterexample with a finitely generated colimit?

Comment: @MahdiTeymuriGarakani have your read my comment?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your comment.